# Rows aggregation by string concatenation?

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects, webi

I am working on a SAP Webi 4 report where I have a table that looks like

| student | discipline | exam session |
| --- | --- | --- |
| josé | geo | june session |
| josé | geo | september session |
| josé | math | june session |

from which I would like to obtain another table that looks like:

| student | discipline | CONCAT_exam session | NBR_exam session |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| josé | geo | june session; september session | 2 |
| josé | math | june session | 1 |

however I am stuck with the column `CONCAT_exam session`:
I have read dozen of posts like this one https://answers.sap.com/questions/12...ed-on-da.html; and tried the creation of tens of variables, but nothing works and I am not able to obtain the desired output !

Could anyone help ?? after tons of trials, I am really running out of ideas....

Side question: if anyone has a clear explanation/guidance whether I should create new "measure(s)" or "dimension(s)" for this purpose, I would be very grateful !

Comment: [This](http://www.djames.net/BIBlog_Entries/How-to-get-multiple-values-into-one-cell) will get you close. Not sure about the count.

Comment: thanks it put me on the right track !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's my first reply so I have no idea how to format the answer correctly.
I think I have done similar exerice some time ago. Let's try my idea:

1. create such 5 variables:

[v_full_name] -> `=[student]+" "+[discipline]`

[Object 1] -> `=Previous(Self;([v_full_name])) +","+ [exam session]`

[maximum] -> `=Max([exam session]) In ([v_full name])`

[Object 2] -> `=[Object 1] Where ([exam session]=[maximum])`

[CONCAT_exam session] -> `=Substr([Object 2];2;(Length([Object 2])))`

please let me know if it helps